Saxon: Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two or more items
I reached the end with that bug:

Type error on line 243 column 119 of transform.xsl:
FORG0006  Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two or more items starting with a boolean
In template rule with match="table[preceding-sibling::div[@class='sectionclass'][1]/text()[1]='Physical Properties:']/tbody" on line 243 of transform.xsl invoked by built-in template rule (text-only)
In template rule with match="table[@class='cheminfo'][1]" on line 125 of transform.xsl invoked by xsl:apply-templates (tail calls omitted) at file:/home/pyork/Entwicklung/XSLT/Textknoten-Extraktion/Duftwerk/./transform.xsl#113
Effective boolean value is not defined for a sequence of two or more items starting with a boolean

My code for SaxonHE12-5J:
    Line 125: <xsl:template match="table[@class='cheminfo'][1]">
    Line 243: <xsl:template match="table[preceding-sibling::div[@class='sectionclass'][1]/text()[1]='Physical Properties:']/tbody">

I hope I can find the issue in the XPath expression.
I also switched off byte code generation as suggested by Michael Kay:
<configuration xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration">
  <global
    generateByteCode="false"
  /> 
</configuration>

I refer to that config by the shell command:
java -jar ../../Tools/SaxonHE12-5J/saxon-he-12.5.jar \
-s:"transform-input-file-list.xml" \
-xsl:./transform.xsl \
-o:"transform-output.xml"
-config:"saxon.config"


Can you post a test case that reproduces this? It's a little hard to identify the problem in the abstract.

Byte code generation has only ever been a Saxon-EE feature, and it's dropped in Saxon-12, because improvements in the JDK meant that it no longer delivered any benefits.

The error isn't in the code you have shown us. It's probably somewhere in the body of the template rule that starts on line 243. Because it's a run-time error, we may need to see a complete repro, including source data, to help you diagnose it. We'll certainly need to see more of your code.

What can we tell you about the error? We know it's trying to compute the effective boolean value of some expression. That would happen, for example, with a test expression in xsl:if or xsl:when. And we know that the expression's value is a sequence of more than one item whose first item is a boolean. So it would occur with something like <xsl:if test="a=b, c=d"/>. Beyond that, we're working in the dark.

Thank you, Michael, Norm and James for your kind support and explanations.
I am happy to share with you one source document, an XHTML file, and the complete XSLT stylesheet.
So amazing, about 2000 I read Michaels XML book and I really appreciate learning by you even 25 years later about to write better code. Any comments about my style are welcome.

It might be the tr/td/starts-with() checks, use tr/td[starts-with()]

Thank you Martin, you solved an issue of me again
